# Why does the Python function not print a default value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and am attempting to print a default value set for a parameter. My code is as follows;

```
# Functions

def shoppingcart(item='computer', *price):
    print item
    for i in price:
        print i

shoppingcart(100,200,300)
```

When I run the code, all I get are the values `100,200,300`. I was expecting `computer,100,200,300`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

How do I achieve this in Python 2.7?

**EDIT**

I updated my code to

```
def shoppingcart(item='computer', *price):
    print item
    for i in price:
        print i

shoppingcart(item='laptop', 100,200,300)
```

however get the error

[image]

Comment: Python 2 will not let you write `shoppingcart(item='laptop', 100,200,300)`. It doesn't matter how you write the function, because you just can't call it that way.

Comment: As for what the error means: a "keyword arg" is something like `item='laptop'`, where you specify the name and value; a "positional arg' or "non-keyword arg" is something like `100`, where you just specify the value. You have to put the keyword args after all of the positional args whenever you call a function. So, you can write `shoppingcart(100, 200, 300, item='laptop')`—and lqc's code will work if you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible. You can never write this in Python:

```
shoppingcart(item='laptop', 100,200,300)
```

In either 2.x or 3.x, you will get an error:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

First, a little background:

A "keyword" argument is something like `item='laptop'`, where you specify the name and value. A "positional", or "non-keyword" argument, is something like `100`, where you just specify the value. You have to put the keyword args after all of the positional args whenever you call a function. So, you can write `shoppingcart(100, 200, 300, item='laptop')`, but you can't write `shoppingcart(item='laptop', 100, 200, 300)`.

This makes a little more sense when you understand the way keyword arguments are handled. Let's take a very simple case, with a fixed set of parameters and no default values, to make everything easier:

```
def shoppingcart(item, price):
    print item, price
```

Whether I call this with `shoppingcart('laptop', 200)`, `shoppingcart(price=200, item='laptop')`, or any other possibility, you can figure out how the arguments arrive in `item` and `price` in the function body. Except for `shoppingcart(price=200, 'laptop')`, Python can't tell what `laptop` is supposed to be—it's not the first argument, it's not given the explicit keyword `item`, so it can't be the `item`. But it also can't be the `price`, because I've already got that. And if you think it through, it's going to have the same problem any time I try to pass a keyword argument before a positional argument. In more complex cases, it's harder to see why, but it doesn't even work in the simplest case.

So, Python will raise a `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`, without even looking at how your function was defined. So there's no way to change your function definition to make this work; it's just not possible.

But if you moved `item` to the end of the parameter list, then I could call `shoppingcart(100, 200, 300, item='computer')` and everything would be fine, right? Unfortunately, no, because you're using `*args` to soak up the `100, 200, 300`, and you can't put any explicit parameters after a `*args`. As it turns out, there's no principled reason for this restriction, so they did away with it in Python 3—but if you're still using 2.7, you have to live with it. But at least there is a workaround.

The way around this is to use `**kwargs` to soak up all of the keyword arguments and parse them yourself, the same way you used `*args` to soak up all the positional arguments. Just as `*args` gets you a `list` with the positional arguments, `**kwargs` gets you a `dict` with each keyword argument's keyword mapped to its value.

So:

```
>>> def shoppingcart(*args, **kwargs):
...    print args, kwargs
>>> shoppingcart(100, 200, 300, item='laptop')
[100, 200, 300], {'item': 'laptop'}
```

If you want `item` to be mandatory, you just access it like this:

```
item = kwargs['item']
```

If you want it to be optional, with a default value, you do this:

```
item = kwargs.get('item', 'computer')
```

But there's a problem here: You only wanted to accept an optional `item` argument, but now you're actually accepting *any* keyword argument. If you try this with a simple function, you get an error:

```
>>> def simplefunc(a, b, c):
...     print a, b, c
>>> simplefunc(1, 2, 3, 4)
TypeError: simplefunc() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
>>> simplefunc(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
TypeError: simplefunc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'd'
```

There's a very easy way to simulate this with `**kwargs`. Remember that it's just a normal `dict`, so if you take out the expected keywords as you parse them, there should be nothing left over—if there is, the caller passed an unexpected keyword argument. And if you don't want that, you can raise an error. You could write that like this:

```
def shoppingcart(*prices, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        if key != 'item':
            raise TypeError("shoppingcart() got unexpected keyword argument(s) '%s' % kwargs.keys()[0]`)
    item = kwargs.get('item', 'computer')
    print item, prices
```

However, there's a handy shortcut. The `dict.pop` method acts just like `dict.get`, but in addition to returning the value to you, it removes it from the dictionary. And after you've removed `item` (if it's present), if there's anything left, it's an error. So, you can just do this:

```
def shoppingcart(*args, **kwargs):
    item = kwargs.pop('item', 'computer')
    if kwargs: # Something else was in there besides item!
        raise TypeError("shoppingcart() got unexpected keyword argument(s) '%s' % kwargs.keys()[0]`)
```

Unless you're building a reusable library, you can get away with something simpler than that whole `if`/`raise` thing and just do `assert not kwargs`; nobody will care that you get an `AssertionError` instead of a `TypeError`. That's what lqc's solution is doing.

To recap, it doesn't matter how you write your function; it can never be called the way you want. But if you're willing to move `item` to the end, you can both write it and call it in a reasonable way (even if it's not as simple or readable as the Python 3 version).

For some rare cases, there are other ways to go. For example, if prices always have to be numbers, and items are always strings, you can change your code to do something like this:

```
def shoppingcart(*prices):
    if prices and isinstance(prices[0], basestring):
        item = prices.pop(0)
    else:
        item = 'computer'
    print item
    for price in prices:
        print price
```

Now, you can do this:

```
>>> shoppingcart(100, 200, 300)
computer
100
200
300
>>> shoppingcart('laptop', 100, 200, 300) # notice no `item=` here
laptop
100
200
300
```

This is basically the kind of trick Python uses to implement `slice(start=None, stop, step=None)`, and it is very occasionally useful in your code. However, it makes your implementation much more fragile, makes the behavior of your function much less obvious to the reader, and generally just doesn't feel Pythonic. So, it's almost always best to avoid this and just make the caller use real keyword arguments if that's what you want, with the restriction that they have to come at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. A video I am watching from NetTuts places keyword arguments before non-keyword or positional arguments and it works unless I have overlooked something. Also when you say `make the caller use real keyword arguments` what do you mean?

Comment: By "make the caller use real keyword arguments", I mean do things the normal Python way, with actual keyword parameters that have to be passed as arguments, with the restriction that they have to come at the end, instead of coming up with a way of faking something without that restriction.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: As for the video: can you post exactly what they typed to call the function (and, if they wrote the function themselves, exactly how they defined it)? I can't guess whether the video is wrong, or you're misinterpreting it, or what, without knowing that they did.

Comment: I watched the video again and I made the mistake. Sorry. The function they had defined were 2 keyword arguments i.e. `def example(adjective='hungry', name='jesse'): print "%s is very %s" % (adjective, name). I did however learn about keyword arguments, non-keyword arguments and positional arguments. Thank you.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: No problem. If you understand how argument handling actually works, the reasons for the rules are obvious—but otherwise, they really aren't obvious at all, so you just have to learn them, and it's easy to make mistakes. The error message is trying to explain the problem, but it expects you to know terminology you have no reason to have learned yet, so it's understandable that you were confused.

Comment: If you are able to include the answers in the comments `lqc's` in your answer, I will accept your post. Found it easy to understand your answer as you broke it down for me and did not assume I understood everything. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: OK, I think I've got all the information in there now—although it may be so verbose it's hard to _find_ the information you need; if so, I apologize.

Comment: One of the best answers ever. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, default values are only used if there is no other way. Here you have `item=100` and the other 2 values go into `*price`.

In Python3 you can write:

```
def shoppingcart(*prices, item='computer'): 
    print(item)
    print(prices)

shoppingcart(100,200,300)
shoppingcart(100,200,300, item='moon')
```

In Python2 you cannot have default arguments after `*args` so you have to find another way to call your functions.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do the same in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.x you'll have to use the `**` syntax:

```
def shoppingcart(*prices, **kwargs):
   item = kwargs.pop("item", "computer")
   assert not kwargs, "This function only expects 'item' as keyword argument".
   print(item)
   print(prices)
```

Then you can pass it keyword arguments:

```
shoppingcart(100,200,300, item='moon')
```

(They always need to be after 'positional' arguments)

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need to use `pop`? and also what do you mean by 'positional` arguments?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: You use the `pop` to not only `get` the item, but also remove it from the `dict` if present. That means afterward, whether or not the caller passed an `item`, the dict is empty unless they've passed some unexpected keyword arguments. So you can test for that. (It would be better to raise a `TypeError("shoppingcart() got an unexpected keyword argument")` than to `assert`, but unless you're writing a library for others to use or something, this is fine.)

Comment: @lqc - Thanks lqc. Sorry for being a newbie at this but can you give me examples of each as I don't understand what you meant by `get` and where `dict` comes into the picture?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: The `kwargs` is a `dict`. If you call `shoppingcart(100, item='laptop')`, `kwargs` will be `{'item': 'laptop'}`. So, if you want to get the `item` argument, you can do `kwargs['item']`. If you want to get the `item` argument, or a default if the caller didn't pass one, `kwargs.get('item', 'laptop')`. If you want to do that, and also make sure it's the _only_ keyword argument, `kwargs.pop('item', 'laptop')`, `kwargs.pop('item', 'laptop')`, and then check that `kwargs` is empty afterward.

Comment: @abarnert - Please correct me if I am wrong. 1. Because I am doing `**kwargs` it expects a dictionary e.g. `{item:laptop}`. 2. This then allows me to access the key value i.e. `kwargs[item]`. What I don't understand is what you mean by `get the item argument`. I understand that if the caller doesn't pass one I can run `kwargs.get('item', 'laptop'). If I want to pass a default value, I must make sure that it is a keyword argument and I can do so by using `kwargs.pop('item', laptop`). What I do not understand is what you mean by `only` keyword argument and that `kwargs` is empty?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: What I mean by "only" is that if you want it to be an error for the caller to say `shoppingcart(100, 200, 300, item='laptop', discount='theft')`, which you probably do, the way to do that is to check that `item` is the only kwarg. That's why you use `pop` instead of `get`—then you just have to check that `kwargs` is empty after you `pop`ped `'item'`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: As for the rest: The "it" in that first sentence is ambiguous. The caller doesn't have to pass a dictionary, he just does `item='laptop'`  as one of the arguments, but your function body will _receive_ a dictionary in `kwargs`. I think you get that, but I want to be sure. Also, default-valued parameters don't _have_ to be keyword-only; think of `def foo(a=4, b=5)`, which I can call with `foo(3)` and `a` and `b` get 3 and 5. If you want to understand all the details of parameters and arguments, you really need to read the docs or a tutorial; I can't explain it all in comments.

Comment: @abarnert - I think I get it now. Because I pass the value `item=laptop` as one of the arguments and BECAUSE the parameter is defined as **kwargs, it takes the keyword argument and tranposes it as a dictionary. Now if I want to make sure that only keyword argument being passed is `item=laptop`, I use `pop` i.e. `kwargs.pop = ('item', 'laptop')`. If I want to retrieve the value of `kwargs` I would use `kwargs.get('item', 'laptop')` however `'get` does not validate if `item=laptop` is the only keyword argument.